# general authentication for RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

I was wondering what is the best way to handle authentication and what is the process in a RoR app? I am looking to obtain a users email address and password of some number of characters. I stumbled across Devise, would this help?

I am fairly new to the RoR world.

Thanks.

Comment: hello, for general authentication you can use doorkeeper gem

Answer (score 3):

I personally use Devise for all my projects and I think it's the most popular auth solution for Rails (and [Ruby toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=authentication) search seens to confirm that)

Big advantage of Devise is that it works with Omniauth which has plugins to most popular 3rd party auth solutions (Google, Facebook, Github, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Devise gem is usually used, here is a screencast on it: http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise

also you can do it from scratch if you only need some simple logic, here is another screencast on that topic: http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch

hope it helps

Comment: Doing auth by yourself is a stupid idea. There's a lot of security features to take into account one can easily forget about (or be unable to do it properly)

Answer (score 0):

### Pick Your Poison

There are quite a few different ways to provide authentication in Rails, from [rolling your own](http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch) to using any number of [publicly-available gems](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=authentication). There's no one right answer; you'll just need to make a selection based on the features you need, as well as the tools that you think will be the most well-supported.